# Javascript append and undo problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a few problems with javascript. I am trying to create a function for when I click a radio button it will run that function. (I got this to work).

My problem is when I click the radio button to order alphabetically it orders but then when i clicked the other radio buttons to change function it is still ordered alphabetically due to "APPEND" my question is how can I get my program to work so when I kill alphabetically ordered it only orders for that and when i click back to something else its ordered how it was originally.

Here is part of my code:

Javascript:

```
function radiobuttonclicked() {

    var allChampions1 = $(".masterychampsforsum > .colzz");
    var selectedcheckyesnochest = document.getElementsByName("optioncheckradiomasterychamps");

    if (selectedcheckyesnochest[0].checked == true) {
        allChampions1.show();
    }
    else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[1].checked == true) {
        var selectedChampions1 = $(".masterychampsforsum > .colzz[data-chest-champion^='yes']");
        allChampions1.hide();
        selectedChampions1.show();
    }
    else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[2].checked == true) {
        var selectedChampions1 = $(".masterychampsforsum > .colzz[data-ranked-champion^='yes']");
        allChampions1.hide();
        selectedChampions1.show();
    } else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[3].checked == true) {
        var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.colzz').sort(function(a, b) {
            return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('championalphabeta').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('championalphabeta').toLowerCase());
        });
        var container = $("#masterychampsforum");
        container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
        $('.summonerLayout-summary').append(container);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabItem Content SummonerLayoutContent summonerLayout-summary" data-tab-spinner-height="800" data-tab-is-loaded-already="true">
<div class="SearchChampion" style="margin-top:20px;padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #000;background-color: #111111;">
    <form class="SearchChampionForm" onsubmit="return false;" style="position: relative;">

        <input name="optioncheckradiomasterychamps" style="margin-left:15px;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -1px;" type="radio" value="Chest" id="option_all" onclick="radiobuttonclicked();" checked/> <label for="option_all" style="font-size:16px;">ALL</label>
        <input name="optioncheckradiomasterychamps" style="margin-left:15px;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -1px;" type="radio" value="Chest" id="option_chest" onclick="radiobuttonclicked();"/> <label for="option_chest" style="font-size:16px;">CHEST</label>
        <input name="optioncheckradiomasterychamps" style="margin-left:15px;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -1px;" type="radio" value="Ranked" id="option_ranked" onclick="radiobuttonclicked();"/> <label for="option_ranked" style="font-size:16px;">RANKED</label>
        <input name="optioncheckradiomasterychamps" style="margin-left:15px;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -1px;" type="radio" value="Ranked" id="option_alpha" onclick="radiobuttonclicked();"/> <label for="option_alpha" style="font-size:16px;">ALPHABETICAL</label>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="masterychampsforsum" id="masterychampsforum">
<div class="colzz" data-champion-name="'.$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez.'" data-champion-key="'.$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez.'" data-chest-champion="'.$champchestyes.'" data-ranked-champion="'.$checkchampionidyesnotrue.'" data-championalphabeta="'.$getLeagueKeyNamelistsidez.'">


</div>
</div>
```

The data in the data-championalphabeta is Names.

[Link to what i got currently](http://aaronpap.ultimatefreehost.in/novo/profile.php?userName=forsakenhound)

Comment: If you want to get back the original unordered data, you need to make a copy somewhere, and then copy it back when you use the other options.

Comment: How would i make a copy of it ?

Comment: You can use `.clone()` and then append it to a hidden DIV.

Comment: Im trying to do this for a school project and never use java script much

Comment: I have to go now. Read the documentation.

Comment: Done this

function ordermasterys() {
    
    var grab = $('.masterychampsforsum').clone().removeClass('masterychampsforsum').appendTo('#masterychampsforsum2');
   
    
    
   }

Comment: But it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar is right, you have to make a copy first and then you can sort against this copy.

When the last case of your if statement is executed, the DOM is updated.

As the function radiobuttonclicked always retrieves the list from the DOM (the line: var allChampions1 = $(".masterychampsforsum > .colzz")), all the next executions of the function are retrieving the previously ordered list and your original order is lost.

Instead try that (not the best code ever but with this context that will do):

```
var allChampions1
function radiobuttonclicked() {  
    if(!allChampions1)
        allChampions1 = $(".masterychampsforsum > .colzz").clone();

    var selectedcheckyesnochest = document.getElementsByName("optioncheckradiomasterychamps");

    if (selectedcheckyesnochest[0].checked == true) {
        updateContainer(allChampions1);
    } else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[1].checked == true) {
        var selectedChampions1 = allChampions1.filter("[data-chest-champion^='yes']");
        updateContainer(selectedChampions1);
    } else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[2].checked == true) {
        var selectedChampions1 = allChampions1.filter("[data-ranked-champion^='yes']");
        updateContainer(selectedChampions1);
    } else if (selectedcheckyesnochest[3].checked == true) {
        var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = allChampions1.clone().sort(function(a, b) {
            return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('championalphabeta').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('championalphabeta').toLowerCase());
        });
        updateContainer(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    }
}

function updateContainer(newList){
    var container = $("#masterychampsforum");
    container.detach().empty().append(newList);
    $('.summonerLayout-summary').append(container);
}
```

Comment: It still runs in the same way showing everything the same as before, possibly its due to the class and id been the same ?

Comment: I tried a simulation of this code on your site and it worked well for me

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5O13NG  This is what i done, didnt change anything but the script

Comment: sorry I just corrected it. I forgot that the jQuery sort function was not returning a copy.